# Possible to combine multiple TINYINT/boolean columns and return as a bit column in MySQL stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, sql

There's a table with separate columns with TINYINT(1) values, is it possible to combine them and return as a single column with bit (edit: bit field) datatype?

Comment: combine how? a bit can only have 2 values. combining multiple fields into a single bit will lose values. recent mysql versions support true bit fields and will internally use x mod 8 bytes to store them.

Comment: ah yes you're right, is there a way to combine multiple tinyint columns to a bitfield column?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to apply `Logical Operators` on many `TINYINT`columns.

You can use `&&` or `||`.

For details have a look [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/logical-operators.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want [bitwise operators](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/bit-functions.html).
The singluar version of logical operators.

```
BIT_COUNT() Return the number of bits that are set
&   Bitwise AND
~   Invert bits
|   Bitwise OR
^   Bitwise XOR
<<  Left shift
>>  Right shift
```